# GA4 triggers lag on Chrome M1

Tags: apple-m1, google-analytics-4

Our site eskimi.com is experienced a ton of lag/unresponsiveness when scrolling fast and clicking.

We've isolated it to our GA4 tag and only users using Chrome and an Apple M1 (not sure if M2).

We have tried to ad script other sites and same issue.

Has been going on for 2 months and close to removing Google Analytics. Must be a bug somewhere.

Comment: Post the relevant code and what slowness have you measured and what do you expect to help debug it. In it's current form it's simply impossible to answer, and even borderline spam.

Comment: also describe how you've isolated it to the GA4 tag. It's odd that you use the word "tag" while not mentioning GTM or a different TMS anywhere.

Comment: We've isolated it by disabling GA4 from GTM and then it works perfectly. Did a round of asking 10 colleagues and only 3 of them experienced it (they were on M1)

Here's my brief to Webflow with example of it happening. https://www.loom.com/share/e4879b2dacc341e581d208a970ddc39f

GA4 tag setup:
https://ibb.co/gzkkXXn

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section. Also, please use textual content as long as possible